# How to query for an available item

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I just would like to ask for help concerning this equipment inventory and reservation system i am working on...

So... i have 3 tables. `tbl_items`, `tbl_bulk_items`, and `tbl_reservations`.

**tbl_items** contains all the items(equipment classified as per UNIT)

**tbl_items_bulk** contains all the items that are in bulk. e.g. a set of cooking knives(12 pcs/set)

**tbl_reservations** contains all the reservation information

so far, this is my query for getting all the items in both the `tbl_items` and `tbl_items_bulk` tables.

```
SELECT bcode
FROM

/*gets all the items in the inventory*/
(SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items AS T1
UNION
SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items_bulk) AS T2
```

And i would query it against another query to get a list of all the bcodes that doesn't exist in the tbl_reservation(meaning it's available)...

```
/*gets all the items in the inventory that satisfies the given conditions*/
WHERE bcode
NOT IN
(SELECT bcode FROM tbl_test)
```

But the problem is, i need to use conditions(dont quite know how to properly do that) to further filter the query to get all the 'available' items.

here's the conditions...

if the item's bcode is in the reservation table, then it IS unavailable.
OR if it(item bcode) is in the reservation table, but the date and time of the reservation is different from what the user will state, then it can still be counted as available.

e.g. Equipment 1 was reserved 2013-09-16 from 7:30 AM to 10:30 AM. If the user would ask if it is available for another date(let's say 2013-09-17), from 7:30 AM to 10:30 PM, it should show up as 'available'. (I hope I'm making it clearer)

Any ideas as to how I would be able to get all 'available' equipment for a certain date and time?

My current code:

```
SELECT bcode
FROM
/*gets all the items in the inventory*/
(SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items AS T1
UNION
SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items_bulk) AS T2
/*gets all the items in the inventory that satisfies the given conditions*/
WHERE bcode
NOT IN
(SELECT bcode FROM tbl_test WHERE resDate!='2013-09-16')
```

UPDATE 9-17-2013:

LATEST CODE:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_items
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM tbl_items_bulk
     ) b left outer join
     tbl_test t
     on b.bcode = t.bcode and
     NOT ('4:30' < t.timeSTART OR '7:00' > t.timeEND)
WHERE t.bcode is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to see if there are any reservations for `bcode` at a certain time.  I think the following query has the right logic:

```
SELECT b.bcode
FROM (SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items
      UNION
      SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items_bulk
     ) b left outer join
     tbl_reservation r
     on b.bcode = r.bcode and
        @USERTO <= r.ToDate and
        @USERFROM >= r.FromDate
WHERE r.bcode is null;
```

What this does is check to see if there are any reservations that match the `bcode` for a given date using `left outer join`.  Note the date condition is in the `on` clause.  So, if there is a match, then a row will be returned.  If there is no match, then the `bcode` value from the reservations table will be `NULL` -- which is what the `where` clause filters for.

Comment: What does the 'WHERE r.bcode is null' mean? I meant i know that it's a condition that checks if r.bcode is null, but, what is it for? (I am a beginner @ mysql)Thanks for the quick reply. :D

Comment: Wont the code above throw an error because of the ambiguous columns?

Comment: @user2784251 . . . Yes (fixed now).  I had missed the alias on the outer `select`.

Comment: Q: What is the @userdate for?

Comment: is it possible to somehow 'rephrase' this query so that i could better understand it(am a beginner @ mysql)?

Comment: I need to be able to input my own resdate and timeFrom and timeTO.

Comment: Im sorry for such a silly question, what is @USERTO and @USERFROM? are they variables? what do they represent? where do they get their values? again, i apologize because this is the first time i met the @ sign in mysql.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I have one last request. Does this code also filter the dates? What I would like do was first, get all the equipment bcode from tbl_items and tbl_items_bulk, and then see if any of the results from the union has a record in the tbl_reservation. If there are matches, then it will not display the equipment bcode that has a match(because i was trying to get all the bcodes that hasn't been added to tbl_reservations), and do the same with the time...

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, but to answer your question about what the r.bcode is null is doing.

The left outer join means give me all rows from the left table (in this case the result of the union), and all matching rows from the right side (table_reservation).  If a row in the union resultset doesn't have a match in table_reservation, bcode will return as null.  So filtering for nulls on that column will return all rows that do not have a match in table_reservation.

Comment: Oh so, if i dont like to display the one's with the nulls, i just need to use an inner join?

Comment: If I understand you, yes.  Here's an example:
[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5753e/5)

Comment: Q: What is the @userdate for?